# What does P@1 mean in this scientific article?

Tags: statistics, notation

In this scientific article: [Label Filters for Large Scale Multilabel Classification](http://proceedings.mlr.press/v54/niculescu-mizil17a/niculescu-mizil17a.pdf) by Alexandru Niculescu-Mizil and  Ehsan Abbasnejad, they use the notations P@1, P@5 and P@10 as the following table shows

> [image]

I was thinking that they were $p$-values at the beginning, but it somehow doesn't make sense.

Could someone explain me what this notations mean?

Comment: Well, it's not standard.  On a quick glance at the table, $P@ i$ means the performance given $i$ label filters. But perhaps you should ask the authors of the paper?

Comment: http://www.thespermwhale.com/jaseweston/papers/wsabie-ijcai.pdf

Comment: ... "Following previous work on large scale multilabel classification (Weston et al., 2013; Prabhu and Varma, 2014; Bhatia et al., 2015) we use precision at k (P@k) as the evaluation metric"

Comment: thanks, I was looking for P@1 in the article, this is why I didn't see P@k. Next time I will put in the summaries of the articles I work with the unknown notations too if I don't intend to reread them fully

Comment: @ literally is a symbol for "at", it has a long tradition in accounting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The article you linked says:

> Following previous work on large scale multilabel classification
>   (Weston et al., 2013; Prabhu and Varma, 2014; Bhatia et al., 2015) we
>   use precision at k (P@k) as the evaluation metric. Precision at k is
>   defined as the fraction of true labels among the top k predictions
>   made by the classifier.

Generally speaking, precision is a binary metric used to compare the results of the classifier under test with trusted external judgments. It is defined as a proportion of correctly labeled items in items predicted by the classifier, vaguely
$$
\mathrm{precision}=\frac{|\{\text{correctly labeled items}\}\cap\{\text{predicted items}\}|}{|\{\text{predicted items}\}|}.
$$
The @k part means that this metric is evaluated on top $k$ predictions retrieved by the classifier.

Answer (score 2):

On the same page of the figure (Section 4) in the article, the notation is defined as follows:

> "Following previous work on large scale multilabel classification (Weston et al., 2013; Prabhu and Varma, 2014; Bhatia et al., 2015) we use precision at k (P@k) as the
>   evaluation metric. Precision at k is defined as the fraction of true labels among the top k predictions made by the classifier."